# How to use a public static scanner in other methods? (nextLine());

Tags: java, methods, static

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass{

    static public Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String [ ] args)
    {
        anotherMethod();
    }

    static public void anotherMethod()
    {
        String sentence;
        String answer;

        do{
            System.out.println("Lets read a sentence: ");
            String Sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("The sentence read: " + sentence);

            System.out.println("Do you want to repeat?");
            answer = keyboard.next();

        } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
    }

}
```

The result is that after the first run, the program displays `"Lets read a sentence:"` and also `"The sentence read: "` without letting me enter a sentence..

I would like to know the simple way of solving this problem.

Comment: This won't compile...

Comment: sorry. fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you type "yes Hello this is a text sentence<enter>", or just "yes<enter>"? The latter is "yes" followed by a blank line.

Comment: Please start by properly formatting your code and fixing your typos.  Java is case-sensitive.  You are declaring *two* variables of type `String`, one named `sentence` and one `Sentence`.

Comment: A Scanner should rarely be a data member, and never static or public. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what's happening: the program reads input with `nextLine`, then prompts for yes/no, at which point you type `yes`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now `Scanner`'s buffer contain these four characters:

```
'y' 'e' 's' '\n'
```

When you call `next()`, `Scanner` reads characters up to `'\n'` which serves as a delimiter. The letters are removed from the buffer, so `"yes"` becomes the result of `next()`. However, `'\n'` is *not* taken! It is left in the buffer for the next `Scanner` call.

Now the loop comes to its next iteration, your program prompts for more input, and calls `nextLine()`. Remember that `'\n'` in the buffer? That's what your program is going to read right away, ending the input.

You can fix this by replacing the call of `next()` with a call of `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `nextLine()` method for collecting your `answer` string as well.

```
answer = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Otherwise, the `next()` call only returns the string `yes` but leaves a new line character dangling behind that gets scanned at the next iteration of your `while` loop without giving you a chance to enter something.